# CIDR not taking as variable in terraform for AWS provider

Tags: terraform

Cidr block for vpc resource is not taking as parameter. If i hardcode the value it works. please suggest

Not working:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block  = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
```

Working:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block  = "10.0.0.0/16"
```

Comment: whats the variable look like for `vpc_cidr` ?

Comment: variable "vpc_cidr" {default="10.0.0.0/16"}

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Where is the variable being saved? what is the name of the file?